# accessing virtual host with ip address

Tags: android, angularjs, apache

I am building an android app. However i need to access to the localhost which the url is url.dev

On the app, it only accessible via ip 10.0.3.2

May i know how to make my virtual host url accessible via ip address?

As in hosts:

```
10.0.3.2 url.dev
```

As in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost 10.0.3.2
<VirtualHost 10.0.3.2>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\backend"
    ServerName url.dev
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\backend">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride all
      Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you edit the `hosts` file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you edit the `hosts` file on your local computer, not on the Android device. Android device or simulator resolves names with its own `hosts` file in `/system/etc/hosts` **on Android filesystem, not on your computer**. To edit the hosts file via adb, launch the emulator with larger `/system` partition:

```
$ emulator -avd {your_avd_name} -partition-size 512
```

Then remount the `/system` as read-write:

```
$ adb remount
remount succeeded
```

Login to adb shell as root and append the `hosts` file:

```
$ adb shell
> # echo "10.0.3.2 url.dev" >> /system/etc/hosts
> # quit
```

Other option is to  set up your own small DNS server.

Comment: How can i do it on emulator? by genymotion?

Comment: @davidlee on my emulator I can edit `/system/etc/hosts` via `adb shell`. Updated the answer. Please check on yours.